# Downloading Image in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which has an `Imageview` in the `Viewholder`.
The Image is downloaded via `AsyncTask` in the `onBindViewHolder` in the adapter.

The problem is when I scroll down or up, the `onBindViewHolder` is called for recycling the view holder and the Images are downloaded again and again.
Now I understand that this is how `Recyclerview` is supposed to work.
So can anyone tell me if anything can be done to avoid downloading the Images more than once?
Or will it be better to move back to `ListView`?

Comment: Would you please share your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and cache the image. And I guess Picasso Cache the image by default.

**Example**

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Picasso really solved it, though there is a little bit of delay in switching images , It was much better than AsyncTask.

Comment: But this still re-downloads each image on each scroll. Where is your image downloading? In the onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Picasso will cache your image.

Answer (score -1):

hold List of Bitmap or Drawable in adapter's field and get image from that list. You can take image's index by getLayoutPosition() method in onBindViewHolder

Comment: Holding bitmaps in a list,good luck getting an OutOfMemoryException with that

Comment: depends by image size. I use lists for icons and never getted OOM