# RecyclerView: low performance when downloading image from web to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-glide

I am trying to download image from an api to my "recyclerView": using the below approach is working but with low performance:

```
try {
        imageBitmap = dImage.execute(items.get(position).getImageLink()).get();
        holder.recyclerImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When googling the issue i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692872/downloading-image-in-recyclerview) answer using picasso in stackoverflow, and [another](https://medium.com/@burhanrashid52/aspect-ratio-in-staggered-layoutmanager-using-constraint-layout-9845d04d1962) using glide.
So I decided to try the since the Picasso didn't work, and made this:

```
    RequestOptions request = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                .error(R.drawable.place_holder_error)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);

    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(request)
                .load(imgUrl)
                .into(holder.recyclerImage);
```

but the images didn't download this time and the `R.drawable.place_holder_error` was displayed, and if the `.error(R.drawable.place_holder_error` is not there nothing is displayed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: While using Glide, when the image is not loaded, is there any error message displayed in the logcat?

Comment: I got this error message: "There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/982\/41967695311_78b994ae09_m.jpg)" .. although the same url works when executing on asyncTask